# How serialized protobuf text format looks like?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Given the following proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tutorial;

message MyMessage {
    string my_value = 1;
}
```

How the corresponding serialized text file should look like?

```
my_value : "abc"
```

or

```
MyMessage {
    my_value : "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither. There are two data formats found in protobuf; the more common is the binary protobuf format; the second (and rarer) is an opinionated JSON variant. So; if we assume that you're talking about the JSON version, we would expect valid JSON (note that I'm not accounting for whitespace here) similar to:

```
{
    "my_value" : "abc"
}
```